# How to delete TensorFlow custom op instance?

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

I'm playing with the [custom op tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op) in TensorFlow.

I implemented the custom op in C++ and created a shared library. I'm loading it using python tf.load_op_library function call. Then I call the custom op using session.run().

The custom op works fine. But I could not figure out when the destructor of the custom is called.

Even-though I have a print statement in the destructor of the custom op, it never get printed. It seems that the custom op instance never get destructed.

Is this the expected behavior and if that is the case, is there a way to inform tensorflow that I'm done using the custom op?

Note that this behavior is noticed only when we use tf.placeholders. If I make the input matrix a constant, i.e.,

> x=zero_out_module.zero_out([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

then the destructor of the custom op get called.

Custom op implementation in C++

```
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/shape_inference.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h"

using namespace tensorflow;

REGISTER_OP("ZeroOut")
    .Input("to_zero: int32")
    .Output("zeroed: int32")
    .SetShapeFn([](::tensorflow::shape_inference::InferenceContext* c) {
      c->set_output(0, c->input(0));
      return Status::OK();
    });

class ZeroOutOp : public OpKernel {
 public:
  explicit ZeroOutOp(OpKernelConstruction* context) : OpKernel(context) {
    printf("Constructor: ZeroOutOp\n"); fflush(stdout);
  }

  ~ZeroOutOp() override {
   printf("Destructor: ZeroOutOp\n"); fflush(stdout);
  }

  void Compute(OpKernelContext* context) override {
    // Grab the input tensor
    const Tensor& input_tensor = context->input(0);
    auto input = input_tensor.flat<int32>();

    // Create an output tensor
    Tensor* output_tensor = NULL;
    OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->allocate_output(0, input_tensor.shape(),
                                                     &output_tensor));
    auto output_flat = output_tensor->flat<int32>();

    // Set all but the first element of the output tensor to 0.
    const int N = input.size();
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
      output_flat(i) = 0;
    }

    // Preserve the first input value if possible.
    if (N > 0) output_flat(0) = input(0);
  }
};

REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("ZeroOut").Device(DEVICE_CPU), ZeroOutOp);
```

Python code to test the custom op

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

zero_out_module = tf.load_op_library('./lib/zero_out/zero_out.so')

inmat=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
    input_mat = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
    x=zero_out_module.zero_out(to_zero=input_mat)


sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True, allow_soft_placement=False))
print(sess.run(x, feed_dict={input_mat:inmat}))
```